# Google Goal conversion not working when I download pdf

Tags: google-analytics

Google Goal conversion not working when I download pdf.
Here I followed following steps:

```
<html>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<a href="/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/SEO-ebook-Final.pdf" onClick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/SEO-ebook-Final.pdf']);">Ok<a/ class='bold-uppercase'>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[gaq.push](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) us classic Google analytics code as in ga.js.  Your Google Analytics snippet shows you are using analytics.js which is universal analytics.

So basically you are mixing things you shouldn't be.

```
<script>
/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
You'll also need to add (or modify) the onclick attribute to your links. Use this example as a model for your own links:

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

code ripped from [Track outbound links](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en)